# Angular: Explanation parameter type on class HttpParams [param: string]: string | string[];

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using HttpParams that is the following constructor:

```
constructor(options?: {
        fromString?: string | undefined;
        fromObject?: {
            [param: string]: string | string[];
        } | undefined;
        encoder?: HttpParameterCodec | undefined;
});
```

Can anyone explane me the meaning fromObject parameter and how to use it?

```
romObject?: {
     [param: string]: string | string[];
} | undefined;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an optional parameter in the options argument of the constructor.
It means options (that's passed in the constructor) can have a `fromObject` property (it's not mandatory). If it's present, it must be a map where the key is a string and the value is either string or a string array (`string|string[]`), or it can also be `undefined`.

So the following are valid

```
const params = new HttpParams({fromObject: {bla: 'test'}});
const params = new HttpParams({fromObject: {bla: ['test1', 'test2']}});
const params = new HttpParams({fromObject: undefined});
const params = new HttpParams({});
```

this is not valid:

```
const params = new HttpParams({fromObject: 'this will fail'});
```